# Как поставить timeout на HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, android

Я отправляю данные на сервер и для этого использую `AsynTask` и в методе `doInBackgraund()` выполняю отправку

```
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", newValue);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.connect();

bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
bos.write(data);
bos.flush();
```

Но, что делать если что то с соединением? У меня реализовано так, что когда данные начинают отправку включается `ProgressDialog()` и когда отправка завершается он выключается. Но когда что то с соединением, он продолжает крутиться и ничего не происходит.

Можно ли как то поставить счетчик на то, что если что то с соединением, то через 5 сек выключить и показать ошибку отправки.?

Но здесь и второй момент, что может быть плохое соединение с интернетом и данные просто из за этого долго отправляются.

Как сделать, чтоб функция ошибки срабатывала именно в случае если что то с соединением или с сервером?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать метод:

```
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
```

Если сервер не успеет ответить, будет исключение

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, это `Timeout` сначала отправки данных... То есть в ситуации, если обьем данных большой или слабый интернет, и время передачи 2 минуты, а `Timeout` стоит на 1 минуту, то процесс отправки прирвется, верно?

Comment: Нет, это именно на установку соединения. Если соединение за указанное время было установлено - исключения не будет.
Для установки таймаута чтения данных есть:

    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(socketTimeout);

Comment: Я вот хотел еще спросить) Как вы считаете я поставил время ожидания 20 сек = 20000, это нормально?

Comment: 20 сек, мне кажется - это многовато.. Я бы поставил что-то около 10. Но тут надо смотреть на прикладную задачу, вполне вероятно, что и 20 в вашем случае будет нормальным)